# Pass only selected checkboxes and attributed input textboxes via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that shows items and the current inventory. Next to each row of inventory, I have a checkbox and a textbox.

The webpage shows the current inventory and gives options for removing selected stock from inventory. So basically checking out items from stock.

[image: pic]

I'd like to be able to pass both the selected item and the inputted amounts to be removed from stock via jQuery but I am having trouble finding the best way to 'serialize' both the checkbox and the text input.

I've tried a number of strategies based off other SO questions, but I only seem to be able to grab either the checked box value or all of the text input values but not the checked box value and only the input value of the checked box.

**What I am trying to get:**

*Checked Apple & entered 5*: `box=Apple&amt=5`

**What I've tried (seen in on('submit') function):**

**What I am getting when using** `var details = $('input[name="box"]:checked').serialize();`:

*Checked Apple & entered 5*: `box=Apple`

**What I am getting when using** `var details = $('#checkout_form').serialize();
                                                      or 
                            var details = $('input[id="amt"]').serialize();`
:

*Checked Apple & entered 5*: `Apple=5&Banana=&Corn=&Deli%20Sandwich=&....`

Here is the jQuery code for displaying the table from JSON data and for passing the data to PHP:

```
  var url = 'get_students.php';
  var $list = $('#inventory');

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      data: {
        command: 'get_inventory',
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        $list.html('<div id="load" class="spinner-border text-muted"></div>');
      },

      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        DISPLAY_INVENTORY(data);
        $('#load').remove();
      },

      fail: function() {
        $list.html('Could not get data ...');
      },

    });
  });

  function DISPLAY_INVENTORY(JSON_DATA) {
    var COL_NAMES = ['Select', 'Item', 'Inventory', 'Amount'];

    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON_DATA);
    var $TABLE_OBJ = $('<table class="table table-striped" >');
    $TABLE_OBJ.attr('id', 'student_table');
    $list.append($TABLE_OBJ);

    // $(output).append($TABLE_OBJ);

    //Print a table header
    var $ROW_OBJ = $('<tr>');
    var $THEAD = $('<thead class="thead-light">');
    $THEAD.append($ROW_OBJ);
    $TABLE_OBJ.append($THEAD);

    for (var j = 0; j < COL_NAMES.length; j++) {
      var $TB_HEADER = $('<th>');
      $TB_HEADER.html(COL_NAMES[j]);
      $ROW_OBJ.append($TB_HEADER);
    }

    $TBODY = $('<tbody>');

    //Print rows
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (i == data.length - 1) {
        $TABLE_OBJ.append($TBODY);
      }

      $ROW_OBJ = $('<tr>');
      $TBODY.append($ROW_OBJ);
      $BOX_OBJ = $('<input name="box" class="form-control ml-4" type="checkbox">');
      $ROW_OBJ.append($BOX_OBJ);
      //Print columns
      $.each(data[i], function(key, value) {
        // if (i % 2 == 0) {
        //   var ITEM_NAME = value;
        // }
        if (key === 'item') {
          rowItemName = value;
        }

        $COL_OBJ = $('<td>');
        $INP_OBJ = $('<input id="amt" class="text-center form-control" type="text" size="3">');
        if (!$INP_OBJ.attr('name') || !($BOX_OBJ.attr('value'))) {
          $INP_OBJ.attr('name', rowItemName);
          $BOX_OBJ.attr('value', rowItemName);
          // $INP_OBJ.attr('id', ITEM_NAME);
        }

        // $INP_OBJ.attr('name', ITEM_NAME);
        // $INP_OBJ.attr('id', ITEM_NAME);
        $COL_OBJ.html(value);
        $ROW_OBJ.append($COL_OBJ);
      });
      $ROW_OBJ.append($INP_OBJ);
    }
  }

  // add form to checkout
  $('#checkout_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // var details = $('#checkout_form').serialize();
        // var details = $('input[name="box"]:checked', 'input[id="amt"]').serialize();
        // var details = $('input[name="box"]:checked').serialize();
        var details = $('input[id="amt"]').serialize();

        console.log(details);

        //Update the info into database table
        $.post(url, {
            command: 'update_inventory',
            log_data: details,
          },
          function(data, status) {
            console.log('Data: ' + data + '\nStatus: ' + status);

            //$status.html(status + ": " + data);
          });
      });
```

Here is the JSON data if needed:

```
[{"item":"Apple","amount":"10"},
{"item":"Banana","amount":"11"},
{"item":"Corn","amount":"12"},
{"item":"Deli Sandwich","amount":"5"},
{"item":"Egg Plant","amount":"12"},
{"item":"French Fries","amount":"15"},
{"item":"Green Beans","amount":"21"},
{"item":"Hamburgers","amount":"7"},
{"item":"Ice Cream","amount":"3"},
{"item":"Jell-O","amount":"12"},
{"item":"Kiwi","amount":"8"},
{"item":"Lima Beans","amount":"32"},
{"item":"Mashed Potatoes","amount":"11"},
{"item":"Noodle Soup","amount":"54"},
{"item":"Orange","amount":"10"},
{"item":"Pear","amount":"5"},
{"item":"Quinoa","amount":"4"},
{"item":"Raisins","amount":"12"},
{"item":"String Cheese","amount":"16"},
{"item":"Tomato Soup","amount":"23"},
{"item":"Unsalted Nuts","amount":"19"},
{"item":"Vienna Sausage","amount":"24"},
{"item":"Wheat Bread","amount":"15"},
{"item":"Xavier Soup","amount":"17"},
{"item":"Yogurt","amount":"11"},
{"item":"Zucchini","amount":"12"}]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- ------------------------------------- -->
  <!-- LOAD EXTERNAL STYLES -->
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Fonts and Icons -->
  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/octicons/8.5.0/build.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://txwes.edu/media/twu/style-assets/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

  <!-- ------------------------------------- -->
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%
    }

    body {
      background: url('img/bg.jpg');
    }

    .container {
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .fas {
      color: black !important
    }
  </style>
  <title>Checkout</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Header -->
  <div class="jumbotron text-center h-auto " style="background: rgba(244, 226, 66,0.5); border-bottom: 5px outset rgb(244, 226, 66);">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/ramlogo3.png" alt="ramlogo"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1>Checkout</h1>
      <form id="checkout_form" method="post">
        <div id="inventory" class="text-center border border-primary rounded p-3" style="overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; height:400px;"></div><br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button">Checkout</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
...see above...
</script>

</html>
```

Please let me know if any more explanation is needed, thank you for the help!

Comment: From what I understand you want to serialize a row of forms not the entire form?

Comment: @KalimahApps Added the HTML, I tried serializing the form but it would send all rows which would mess with the PHP -> SQL commands I am performing in the back end so I would like it to only pass the selected rows and their values.

Comment: if you need to send data back to PHP would not make sense to send only the id and then process database based on that?

Comment: @KalimahApps I'm not totally following, do you mean to pass the id of the form? or id or the inputs?

Comment: I was talking about the flow in general. You said you need to remove those elements so why serialize all input data. If you want to send data from JavaScript to PHP, the easier option is to send a single value (like id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To serialize your data in a single row you can try this code:

```
 var details = $('input[name="box"]:checked').closest("tr").find("input").serialize();
```

Comment: This answered my question and gave me the solution I was looking for but upon further thought, I may need to rethink the structure of how I am going to send the data to the PHP file to edit the SQL table. Thank you for taking the time to help me.